# Is it possible to bundle multiple static libraries into a single static library[C++]?

Tags: c++, static-linking

I created a static library for my C++ code that depends on Boost, OpenSSL, CURL, and Threads in a CentOS 7 environment.

Is it possible to bundle `libboost_system.a`, `libssl.a`, `libcrypto.a`, `libcurl.a`, `libpthread.a` alongside my C++ library into a single library?

Comment: Possible but unwise. You want to keep your dependencies separate from your own code, even your own object code. There's no good reason to do this.

Answer (score 6):

`.a` files are just archives; you can use the `ar` command to manipulate them.

So you could extract all the objects (`ar x`) from each of the libraries and then create a new library (`ar a`) with all the individual files.

However this probably isn't a good idea because it means you have to keep rebuilding this each time one of the upstream libraries changes (eg due to a security issue being fixed).

It's normal for a program to have multiple library dependencies and inclusions.

Comment: I tried `ar -x libboost_system.a` but it gives me an `error_code.o`.

Comment: That sounds normal.  `error_code.o` is an object inside of `libboost_system.a`.  Now use `ar a` to put that object into your library. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/system/doc/html/system.html#ref_class_error_code

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you. I guess there should be more objects inside `libboost_system.a`. Is that a true statement?

Comment: @AFPP It's a question you can answer yourself with the `ar tv` command. No point in asking it here.