# How to bundle a static library with an import library (or two static libraries) with lib.exe?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, static-libraries, dllimport

Import libraries for DLLs on Windows are a peculiar thing. They donate the glue necessary for the linker to create import stubs in the resulting PE file (be it named `.dll` or `.exe` or whatever else).

[This Q&A provides details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67782120/476371) on how to bundle two static libraries on the Unix side. How to achieve the same on Windows with Visual C++?

Also, is there a way to combine static and import libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While other Q&As here would have you think otherwise and even Microsoft doesn't seem to document the possibility, I have seen what I would call a hybrid static/import library distributed in the SDK of a certain hardware vendor.

Generally combining/bundling two static libraries is straightforward with the Library Manager (`lib.exe`), which   by the way   is merely a shallow wrapper invoking `link.exe /lib` and passing on any arguments. You'd use it like this:

```
> lib.exe /nologo /out:combined.lib static1.lib static2.lib
```

Easy. But reversal of the process is not as straightforward, because you need to specify each of the `.obj` files including their relative path in `lib.exe /remove:...`. So essentially without knowing what `.obj` belonged to which static library originally is a prerequisite.

If you wanted to combine a static library and two import libraries, you would use `lib.exe` like so:

```
> lib.exe /nologo /out:hybrid.lib static.lib dll1.lib dll2.lib
dll2.lib(dll2.dll) : warning LNK4006: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in dll1.lib(dll1.dll); second definition ignored
```

In this particular case the warning is benign and can be ignored, but it *does* tell us one thing: **merging two libraries may cause issues if the same symbol is defined more than once**. I suggest *never* to `/ignore:...` this warning **ever**, if you follow any of the examples from this Q&A.

Additionally you cannot merge two libraries containing the same paths to an `.obj` file.

However, reversing the bundling of import libraries into a hybrid static/import library is *more* straightforward, because the member name we ought to remove to get rid of the import library is the DLL name.

So we can do this:

```
> lib /nologo /remove:dll1.dll hybrid.lib
```

But there's a potential issue here and I have never tried all the variations of this scenario. Remember how we got this warning?:

```
dll2.lib(dll2.dll) : warning LNK4006: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in dll1.lib(dll1.dll); second definition ignored
```

If I now remove *only* the `dll1.dll` member, there is likely no more `__NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` left inside our `hybrid.lib`. It stands to reason that `link.exe` will barf on us as soon as we try to build a PE file using this hybrid library. But we could get lucky if there are other import libraries on the command line that donate a usable `__NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` symbol.

Using this hybrid static/import library *will* work, but if you remove bits and pieces it's probably better to remove *all* import library parts from it at once. You could the  technically start over.

##### Some warnings

This is most likely not how things were intended to be used. The shown methods have limitations and require that you know what you do:

1. the individual parts from which the combined (or hybrid) library is created must not have symbol name clashes, unless the symbol names definitely supply the exact same thing to the linker (`__NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` from an arbitrary import library should be harmless, for example)

   - The names and paths of object files also must not clash
2. a newer version of an import library may have to be used for software down the road and so you may find yourself taking apart the hybrid library anyway
3. even if you know what you're doing and even if you have a Raymond-Chen-like overview of all the variables, chances are **YOU STILL DO NOT WANT TO USE THIS**. Be it on account of the fact that it's outright surprising to find an import library combined into a static library. Or be it on account of the fact that your successor or future developers may not know all the details and   to add insult to injury   you forgot to document your unorthodox doings ...

##### Some more information

- The `.lib` files created and processed by Visual C++ are also technically *just* `ar` archives, as often is the case on Unix

  - You can use tools like 7-Zip to unpack and inspect them (re-packaging them is typically harder).

    - Conversely you can use `ar` on a Linux, say, to process `.lib` files originating on Windows (with some caveats due to the path separators etc)
  - While on the Unix side the contained `.o` files will often be ELF files in their own right, for Visual C++ the contained `.obj` files are COFF.
  - You can use tools such as [`objconv`](https://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv) or the [Binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) tools to manipulate these files. The latter have to be specifically built to support COFF and the architectures relevant for your specific `.lib` files.